# Selecting two windows at the same time on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

I am looking for a program that would allow me to select two windows at the same time on Windows 7. Any license or price is fine.

Use case: I sometimes want to perform concurrently the same window operation on two windows, e.g. moving or resizing them. I'd like to select multiple windows by holding down <kbd>CTLR</kbd>, as we can do to select multiple items in a list in many programs.

Comment: You have funny requests. When resizing, should the Windows just be resized or should they also keep their relative positions to each other? Not that I'd know a software that could roughly achieve the task...

Comment: @ThomasWeller just be resized  would be good enough

Comment: I don't think that will work given Windows concept of an "active window/frame".

Comment: Do you have a dual monitors? That should do it. In my work, I open two the same software and it runs fine.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Before I post an answer, does [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap) do what you're looking for? I just want to make sure it's a solution before I answer.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, looks neat, answer welcome.

Comment: @PROBERT 7 monitors. The goal here is to perform the same action on more than one window at once.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, in Windows you can only have 1 window at a time "on top" and "in focus". So you can't select 2+ windows to be "in focus" simultaneously.

However, if what you need is to have your keystrokes processed by 2+ windows, this is something you can achieve. The proper technical solution is to have keystrokes registered by the 1 window that is "in focus" and then use something to clone or resend the same keystrokes to other windows.

The only [solution I've found](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/106529-how-to-send-keystrokes-to-a-multiple-windows-that-have-the-same-process-names/) is to use AutoHotkey with some kind of custom script. Unfortunately, scripting for AutoHotkey is not mindlessly easy but, for this particular problem, it doesn't seem prohibitively hard either.

Cloning mouse movements/clicks seems like a much harder problem since the 2+ windows can have random locations, sizes, etc. [Here is an attempt to solve this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/393738/can-i-mirror-duplicate-mouse-events-on-both-halves-of-my-screen).

Comment: Technically you can have sessions and desktops and you can have an active window per desktop I'd say. There's also just one mouse cursor per Desktop, but people manage to have 4 of them. Imagine something like UltraMon, which adds more buttons to the title bar. It could work, but I wonder whether it will ever be worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend AquaSnap, it's an application that lets you easily arrange and organize windows. It has quite a few features in the free version which include,

- Window Docking
- Window Snapping
- Window Stretching
- Window Shaking
- Make a window transparent
- Make a window stay on top
- Automatic updates
- Keyboard shortcuts

And with a $9 upgrade, it gives, even more, features including,

- Mouse shortcuts
- Window tiling
- Move windows together
- Multi-monitor support

## [AquaSnap](http://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap) ([free](http://www.nurgo-software.com/pricing/aquasnap))

#### ([with optional upgrade](http://www.nurgo-software.com/pricing/aquasnap))

> Aquasnap is a powerful window manager that helps you arrange and
> organize multiple applications on your desktop with minimum effort. It
> allows you to achieve maximum multitasking, especially if you own a
> high-resolution monitor or a multi-monitor setup.
>
> With simple gestures (window docking), you are able to split your
> screen in 2, 3 or 4 areas and to easily adjust the layout to best fit
> your needs. By making your windows behave like magnets (window
> snapping), it allows you to efficiently align them without losing a
> pixel. Need to keep an eye on a small window? Just shake it and it
> will become transparent and always on top. AquaSnap also adds many
> easy to remember and customizable keyboard shortcuts to make you even
> more productive. And these are only some examples of what AquaSnap has
> to offer, try it and be amazed!
>
> [image: AquaSnap in action Screenshot]